# decoupling object construction tied to input data

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection

## What I'm doing

I'm using Dependency Injection to decouple my classes.

## How I'm trying to do it

The class I am making constructs `ObjectImplementation` (the interface) Objects to hold data and it acts as a sort of container. I'm doing this to parse data and cross reference two data-sets. My problem is that I currently have object construction tied to the data being formatted a certain way. I am using the `Factory` pattern and a properties file `"config.properties"`.

## What I want to be able to do

I want to be able to have the factory take in an array of fields or some other similar type and be able to construct instances of the reflected object type without dependencies on the data. In this case they are `Salesrep` instances but other times I want to construct `Salesrep` instances or other classtype instances with different fields filled and different ones `null` without formatting the data to contain the names of fields.

## The end goal

The point is so that I can construct different objects with the same container code. If I want to contain the objects differently I'll simply make a new implementation of the parent interface of this container class.

## What I'm thinking is the problem

I've figured out that a `Fieldmap` was a good idea through previous versions of this question and my own research. Yet there is no way to actually set those fields without having something in the data to match to the `Fieldmap`

## Extra Clarification

I really want to know if I can find a way to achieve my goal without adding field names to the data

```
//creates new properties object and loads in the file configuration
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(SalesRepbyId.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

//reflects in the class we wish to use
Class<? extends ObjectImplementation> Classtouse = Class.forName(prop.getProperty("ObjectImplementation")).asSubclass(ObjectImplementation.class);

//initializes the data and some hashmaps to store the data or the methods of the reflected class
ArrayList<String[]> Salesrep_contactlist = FileParser.ReadFile();
        Map<String, ObjectImplementation> SalesrepByIdMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Method> MethodMap = new HashMap<>();

//adds in the data (fields) by constructing objects of the reflected type using the ObjectImplementation interface
for (String[] fieldarray : Salesrep_contactlist) {
            ObjectImplementation object_to_add = null;
            try {
//utilizes the factory pattern to return an instance of the reflected class
                object_to_add = Factory.getObjectImpl(prop.getProperty("ObjectImplementation"),fieldarray);
/**
uses a method hashmap to map the name of the method to the Method object. 
I did it this way because dynamic variable declarations are not possible and 
I wanted to decouple Method declarations from the specific class that has 
them. If i just hardcoded in which methods I get from the implementing class 
that introduces extra dependencies I don't want. 
**/
                for (Method method:Classtouse.getMethods()) {
                    MethodMap.put(method.getName(),method);
                }
//same as above but for fields this time
                for (Field field:Classtouse.getFields()) {
                    FieldMap.put(field.getName(),field);
                }
//object_to_add is a String[] with the format [Fieldname1:fieldinput1,Fieldname2:Fieldinput2] 
//so I want to get this array and get each element, seperate the fieldname and then use that string to access the actual Field object of the same name in FieldMap
            String fieldname = object_to_add.get(0).split(":").get(0)
            String fieldinput = object_to_add.get(0).split(":").get(1)
            Field name_example = Fieldmap.get(fieldname)
            name_example.set(String.class,fieldinput)
//This requires the data to have the fieldname in it rather than just the fieldinput (or data). Also it confines the input to be strings because I don't think I can use a generic type to set this field even though potentially I would want to.
```

Comment: Why you want to create own solution instead of using something already ready to use? Also in java you should use variable names in lowerCamelCase (first letter is always lower case one)

Comment: also `name_example.set(String.class,fieldinput)` is invalid, first argument should be an object to use, so object that is instance of class that have this field. So probably `object_to_add` in your case.

Comment: Otherwise I don't understand your problem at all, can you maybe explain that final goal better? or create psuedocode of something you want to achieve with example data too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for me to dynamically set Field types without something to go off of in the data or elsewhere. In order to avoid something hard coded like: `Salesrep rep = new rep (arg1,arg2,arg3 ...)` I needed to use the `Fieldmap` and be able to match the data coming in to what fields I wanted to set. Since I didn't want to do it by order ex:

```
List list = new list("bob","800-352-4324","foo@example.com"); 
int i = 0;
for(i = 0, i > list.size(), i++){
    Field field = new Field(//need a name here automatically rather than hardcoded)
    field.set(object_to_add,list[i])
    i++
}
```

The above didn't have any reference to the actual name of the `Field` that I actually use in my class. I didn't want that and then it dawned on me that the first line of my data (which is in `CSV` format) has the `Field` names effectively listed. ex:

(in the `CSV` File) `foo.txt`:

```
1: name,phonenumber,email
2: "bob","800-352-4324","foo@example.com"
3: "steve","800-444-4444","annoyingcommercials@example.com"
4: ...
```

Using this knowledge My solution is to use the first line of my data to specify the field names and their order so that when I take in lines as an array of these strings I can use the first line array as a reference to how to set the fields. I will know that the first element in the array should be the `name` the second should be the `number` ect ect. This way I only have to change the first line if I want to change how many fields the data holding class actually has.

puesdocode:

```
ObjectImpl. Classtouse = refelct in the class to use here from properties file
List(String[]) fieldarray = the raw data taken in and converted to a list of string arrays
String[] firstline = fieldarray.getfirstline()
List(String[]) restoflines = fieldarray.getallotherlines()
for i = 0, i > firstline.size(), i++{
    Fieldmap.put(Name of the field from firstline[i], create a new Field object here with the Name);
    Field fieldtoset = Fieldmap.get(Name of the field again)
    fieldtoset.set(make an instance of the Classtouse here, restoflines[i] which represents the data in the 'Name' column)
```

}

For some silly reason I had it in my head that there was a way to do this without any change to the data, as if the `Factory` which created the object could take in arbitrary/generic arguments and somehow just know where each field went. I realized that that was silly because I needed to tell the code how to actually set the fields but In a way that it wasn't hard-coded into the class. This solution puts the dependency on the data so now its not hard-coded into the class. I should have seen this sooner.